# Can you disable logging in as other users over ssh?

Tags: mac, ssh, sshd

I have a Macintosh server computer with 3 users: admin, git, and server. Admin is the only administrator on the computer, while git and server are normal users. I can log in to all 3 over ssh, using public key authentication only for admin and server, while password authentication is enabled for git.

In short, I want to be able to log in directly to all 3 accounts via ssh, but only be able to switch accounts using su when I logged in first using admin. Is there a way to configure this in sshd_config?

Alternatively, is there a way you can disable su only for certain users?

The server is a a Mac Mini running macOS 10.13.5 and I am using the SSH server from the sharing menu, if that info is important.

Comment: Switching users after logging in has nothing to do with sshd.

Comment: Then is there a way to disable it only for users logged in via ssh?

Can you disable the privilege for only certain users?

Comment: I know it can be done with PAM, but I have no idea how to do it under OS X.

Comment: I believe OS X uses PAM